# "Always on Top" Windows with Java

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, awt

In Java, is there a way to have a window that is "Always on top" regardless if the user switches focus to another application?  I've searched the web, and all of the solutions lean to some sort of JNI interface with native bindings.  Truly this can't be the only way to do it?.. or is it?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Try this method of the `Window` class:

[Window.setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29)

It works the same way as the default in the Windows TaskManager: switch to another app but it shows always on top.

This was added in Java 1.5

Sample code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Annoying {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello!!");

        // Set's the window to be "always on top"
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop( true );

        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.add( new JLabel("  Isn't this annoying?") );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

[image]

<sub>Window remains on top even when is not active</sub>

Comment: you would think a simple search for "java application always on top" on would have this answer, but it couldn't find it.  Thanks.

Comment: Guess what. Now it does!! :)  It brings you here! http://www.google.com/search?&q=java+application+always+on+top

Comment: This is simple and awesome. I was also looking for something like this, but didn't know they implemented this in Java 1.5. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me when running a full screen application such as a video game. Anyone know of a way to force it to the top in that situation?

Comment: @Dream lane I'd probably ask that as a new question

Comment: This works for a login dialog box but my main application window then goes to the background. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: This is like the first code I've seen anywhere ever that pads out boolean parameters with spaces.

Comment: @MMJZ haha true. Actually I'm surprised I didn't  do it for the `args` declaration. I **always** use space after parenthesis. This is a very very old habit that I develop back in the days I used notepad to program. Double clicking on a word would select the parenthesis if there is no space between, which was very annoying because I had to delete them afterwards if what I intended to do was re-use the variable somewhere else.

Comment: This works great but if the user switches to different desktop/screen in mac or linux how to make it show in that screen also

Comment: Does not work if Google Chrome DevTools are opened: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58371767/how-to-show-java-filedialog-in-front-of-google-dev-tools-alwaysontop-does-not-w

Comment: @Stefan hm yes it does https://i.stack.imgur.com/H99Ra.png (11yrs later, that code still runs)

Comment: lol, "Hello!! Isn't this annoying?" Indeed it is VERY annoying when a window obstructs my entire desktop (and other apps during alt-tab). `setAlwaysOnTop` should be rarely used for very extreme cases (like the task manager or other system-wide window) or if the user specifically requested it.

Comment: this answer is spam. OP answer meant to have a aplication window from already opened windows. not to create a window in java

Answer (score 11):

From my observation I found that AlwaysOnTop privilege is given to the latest process which requested to be always on top.

So, if you have an application which `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` and later another application uses this option, the privilege is given to the second application. In order to work around this I have set the `setAlwaysOnTop(false)` and again `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` whenever any window comes on top of the current window.

I've checked it with `wordweb` in `windows`. WordWeb is one of the applications which uses `AlwaysOnTop` option from the `OS`

I'm not sure about if it works properly with your game scenario.

**Warning**: I'm not aware of the side effects.

Here is the code example:

```
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements WindowFocusListener
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        addWindowFocusListener(this);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        this.setFocusable(true);
       // this.setFocusableWindowState(true);
        panel = new JPanel();
        //setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLocation(X,Y);
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e){}
    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getNewState()!=e.WINDOW_CLOSED){
            //toFront();
            //requestFocus();
            setAlwaysOnTop(false);
            setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            //requestFocusInWindow();
            System.out.println("focus lost");
        }

    }

    private JPanel panel;
    private static final int WIDTH = 200;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 200;
    private static final int X = 100;
    private static final int Y = 100;

    public static void main(String args[]){
              new MainWindow();}
    }
```

Comment: Setting it to false and true again when another window comes on top doesn't sound like a workable solution for one simple reason - what if the other application does the same thing?

Comment: @Trejkaz Well, that's a valid point. I'm no longer in touch with swing now.

Comment: This works for my use-case perfectly! Setting it back to false first was key.

Answer (score -1):

dont use setFullScreenWindow,just get the screen size and then setSize, and everything will be fine.

Comment: Is it an answer or comment?

Comment: @FailedScientist a glorified comment