# Is there any way to make JFrame in front of applications outside windows? For example during playing any game on full screen?

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to make my Chat GUI in front of all the applications **not only in windows**. AlwaysOnTop does not solve this problem. As I mentioned mainly during playing games on full screen. I couldn't find anything on the internet so here I am :P

**EDIT:** I found out that if you change display settings in the game to "Borderless" or "Windowed full screen" your GUI window will stay on top with "AlwaysOnTop". Thanks for help anyways.

Comment: [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+keep+jframe+on+top)

Comment: Otherwise JNI or JNA. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386051/keeping-window-ontop-of-all-other-windows-c-java)\

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a JFrame to be always on top. Et voila,

JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
frame.setAlwaysOnTop (true);

Comment: yea but this does not work outside windows