# swing: make a window never lose focus

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Always on Top” Windows with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297938/always-on-top-windows-with-java)

I am using JFrames

I have a window(ex-Accounts) which gets called from a button in MainMenu.

As long as Accounts is opened i want to forbid the user from accessing MainMenu(which should be visible) unless he closes the Accounts window.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you need your window to be modal. JDialog can be modal, you can either mention this in the constructor like this:

```
new JDialog(parent, true);
```

or starting with Java 1.6, you can set the ModalityType:

```
new JDialog(parent, modalityType);
```

Comment: i want to add such a property to a JFrame that i created(say accounts)

i am an immature
i tried using setEnable(false) on the previous window(say mainMenu)
and after returning back from the accounts i set the mainMenu enabled again
bt it did'nt work out

Comment: Note that JOptionPane is a Dialog, so if you want to copy the exact behavior, just use JDialog.

Comment: isn't there any other option that can be used in Jframe

all i want is TO FORBID USER FROM SELECTING ANY OUTER WINDOW, not the exact behavior of JDaialog

Comment: I don't know of any other being available there.

Comment: @VikashSinghSisodia if you're attempting to stop people from interacting with windows outside the context of your application, then don't, just don't. If your interested in just your application, then JDialog is you best option. Tale closer look @ Dialog.ModalityType http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html