# Is there a way to make my Java Applet always on Top even in fullscreen?

Tags: java, applet

Google Searching hasn't helped me find the answer to this.

I was wondering if there is a way to make a java Applet always on top, even when there are fullscreen applications.

Specifically I want to over-lay the applet on top of a Power-Point presentation. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Thank You!

Comment: No it isn't. It is the window manager which controls this sort of things. And it is a rude thing to do anyway.

Comment: may this is useful for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297938/always-on-top-windows-with-java

Comment: How can I do this for an Applet since it does not use a JFrame?