# Java place other windows app below of my swing application

Tags: java, swing

I have a java swing application which is a ticker and it's on top of display. Now I need a way to place other windows applications when they are maximized to be below of my ticker. I mean I don't want my application to overlap other app' s toolbar.

Is there a way to implement such a functionality?

Something like in image, above is my ticker and a chrome can be maximized and the shouldn't overlap toolbar:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Always on Top" Windows with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297938/always-on-top-windows-with-java)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but actually I'm using setAlwaysOnTop method and it's already on top of other windows but when I'm opening let's say chrome and maximize it my application overlaps chrome's toolbar so I want other windows to be below my app.

Comment: Did you read both answers to that question?

Comment: Sure! Always on top is working for me. But my application overlaps toolbar of another app when maximized.

Comment: I thought you meant below in a z-index sense, not an x-y sense. @FredK's answer is the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you maximize an app, you are telling the window manager to "Set the size of this app to be the full size of the screen". Apparently you want that to be "Set the size of this app to be the full screen size, minus the size of my special app" - that is, place it just south of my special app. This is probably not possible without writing your own window manager.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to change the window size of any windows app from my application?