# Is there any possibility to put some process on top/activate the window by using java?

Tags: java, process, always-on-top

I'd like to set some process on top let's imagine for example it's web browser and in some condition it becomes on top - the window activates and I can send there key strokes and some mouse actions.

I've tried to find some in documentation or in web, found only one solution but it's not filling to my problem -  Alt + Tab is required there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Always on Top" Windows with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297938/always-on-top-windows-with-java)

Comment: It's not - I want to Give on top not java application - just as i said for example let's call this application Google Chrome. It's in Tray and when some conditons are filled it's on top and active window.