# JavaWebStart window always on Top

Tags: java, java-web-start

first of all: I have no knowledge in java.

My boss asked me if we could change our current programm to always be on top (like the option in windows task manager - options - "always on top")

Is this possible? I added the code from the current jnlp file we double click to start the programm (i change some personal details like ip adresses and names)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+"
codebase="http://1.1.1.1" 
href="ProgramManager_jnlp.pl?lng=de&amp;cntry=DE">
  <information>
    <title>ProgramManager</title>
    <vendor>xyz GmbH</vendor>
    <description> 132 </description>
    <description kind="short">The Java Client Applications of company xyz</description>
    <homepage href="index.html"/>
    <icon href="images/prettyimage.jpg"/>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
   <j2se version="1.4+" initial-heap-size="512m" max-heap-size="1024m"/>
   <jar href="ProgramManager.jar"/>
   <jar href="Framework.jar"/>
   ...
```

.... = SOME OTHER STUFF that starts with < jar href=>

```
 </resources>

 <application-desc main-class="programmanager.ProgramManager">
   <argument>Host=1.1.1.1</argument>
   <argument>Language=de</argument>
   <argument>Country=DE</argument>
   <argument>Title=JavaWebStart</argument>
   <argument>Resizable=yes</argument>
   <argument>Closeable=no</argument>
   <argument>PrepareGeometryData=yes</argument>
   <argument>Stepback=no</argument>
   <argument>WebStartApplication=yes</argument>
  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Are you aware that Java Web Start has been deprecated since about 3 years ago?

Comment: It's a one liner, but in the java code, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297938/always-on-top-windows-with-java